# didReadRSSI event stops working when entering background with background modes declared

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to develop an app that can discover and connect to devices while in the background, and when the connected peripheral enters a certain rssi range, i would like to send a message to the peripheral.

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didReadRSSI RSSI: NSNumber, error: Error?) {
        // Get the current RSSI value
        let rssi = Int(truncating: RSSI)
            
        print("Current RSSI value: \(String(describing: rssi))")

        let positiveRssi = rssi * -1
        if (positiveRssi <= 50)
        {
            //here i send the message
        }
            
        // Call the readRSSI() method again to get updated RSSI values
        peripheral.readRSSI()
    }
```

when i am in the foreground it works perfectly but when i enter the background it gives me a few more answers and then suddenly stops.

i can see when it is working and when it stops working through the console.
i have also enabled the "Uses Bluetooth LE Accessories" background mode.

Comment: Apps don't continue to run once they are suspended without some sort of background mode. Receiving location updates, playing audio, receiving a CoreBluetooth notification etc.  You can't just keep polling rssi.

Answer (score 0):

As @Paulw11 has already mentioned, mobile operating systems can limit the use of dedicated hardware and resources depending on the state of the application.

Therefore, it might be easier to use standardised Bluetooth LE profiles and services, such as:

- [Proximity Profile 1.0.1](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/proximity-profile-1-0-1/)
- [Link Loss Service 1.0.1](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/link-loss-service-1-0-1/)